# Interface for preventing certain items to be combinational with each other

Tags: forms, interaction-design

Suppose that I have three lists with items [A1, ..., A10], [B1, ..., B10] and [C1, ..., C10] and I apply the cartesian product on those lists. Then I will get [[A1, B1, C1], [A2, B1, C1], ...]

Now I need a user interface that allows a user to define not allowed combinations, for example B1 and C1 cannot be in the same combination.

I have thought about a matrix, but that seems quite cumbersome with many items.

Comment: can you add a mock with the larger context here? Let's see your efforts so far, and are there other constraints we should know about? What is the domain

Comment: It is unclear what the exact use case is here, so if you can provide some more information to set the context and some constraints or requirements that we can work with it will be more helpful. Alternatively you can try and attempt a solution to get some feedback on the design.

Comment: Please show what you have so far. This is a complex design and we need to see your attempt to solve the problem with your understanding of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

That's true it's difficult to visualize 3 levels of list.

Possibility to make it with three-dimensional-matrix:
[image]

For interface it can be simple inputs with values.

I can't understand, why it's not possible to B1 and C1, can be in this same combination?